# How can pass a parameter w/ value to change default and a condition to only run when there is more than one li in UL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

JS

```
(function($) {
$.fn.newsfader = function(opts) {
    // default configuration
    var config = $.extend({}, { 
        fadeInTime: 800,
        fadeOutTime: 800,
        interval: 5600
    }, opts);
    // main function
    function init(obj) {
        var dNewsticker = obj;
        var dFrame = dNewsticker.find('.js-frame');
        var dItem = dFrame.find('.js-item');
        var dCurrent;
        var stop = false;

        dItem.eq(0).addClass('current');
        dItem.eq(0).show();

        var move = setInterval(function(){
            if(!stop){
                dCurrent = dFrame.find('.current');
                dCurrent.fadeOut(config.fadeOutTime, function(){
                    if(dCurrent.next().length !== 0){
                        dCurrent.removeClass('current');
                        dCurrent.next().addClass('current');
                        dCurrent.next().fadeIn(config.fadeInTime);
                    }
                    else{
                        dCurrent.removeClass('current');
                        dItem.eq(0).addClass('current');
                        dItem.eq(0).fadeIn(config.fadeInTime);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, config.interval);

        dNewsticker.on('mouseover mouseout', function(e){
            if(e.type == 'mouseover'){
                stop = true;
            }
            else{
                stop = false;
            }
        });
    }
    // initialize every element
    this.each(function() {
        init($(this));
    });
    return this;
};
// start
$(function() {
    $('.js-newsticker').newsfader(
  //How can i make it work with the new time
  //fadeInTime: 100, fadeOutTime:100

);
});
 })(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="newsticker js-newsticker">
 <ul class="js-frame">
    <li class="js-item">Google shares top $1,000 after strong earnings.</li>
    <li class="js-item">Sleep 'cleans' the brain of toxins.</li>
    <li class="js-item">Amaze project aims to take 3D printing 'into metal age'.</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nolawi/pen/Omyorz?editors=1010#0)

**How can I overwrite parameters. I want to be able to reuse code by being able to change `fadeInTime`? and condition to only run when there is more than one `li` in `ul`**

Comment: Hint: `$.fn.newsfader = function(opts) { var config = $.extend({}, {fadeInTime: 800, ...}, opts}; ... }` -> [How `$.extend()` works](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: @guest271314 My comment should only show him the way. Otherwise I would have posted an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change default settings, pass an object to function with properties and values to set for use within plugin, for example

```
$(".js-newsticker").newsfader({fadeInTime: 100, fadeOutTime:100});
```

You can check if `.length` of `$("li", this)` is greater than `1`, if true, call `init()`. You can also attach `DOMSubtreeModified` event to `this` using `.on()` to call `init` function if both node is appended to element and `.length` of `li` elements of `this` parent element is greater than `1`

```
  if ($("li", this).length > 1) {
      this.each(function() {
        init($(this));
      });
  } else {
      this.on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
        if ($("li", this).length > 1) {
          $(this).off("DOMSubtreeModified").each(function() {
            init($(this));
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that is one method of passing options as parameters.